# How to check if a particular file from one directory also exists in another directory using svnkit

Tags: java, svn, svnkit

I 'm using `Svnkit` and I want to know whether is there any way to check if a particular file from one directory exists in another directory.
For example:

```
//svnlocal/projectA/dir1/file2/xxx.java    
//svnlocal/projectB/dir3/file1/xxx.java
```

I want find the similar files from both the projects and get the revision and date for these similar files.
I have  managed to get revision and date for both the projects .
Thank you in advance!

Here is the code.

```
   import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNWCUtil;

    public class DisplayRep implements Comparator
    {
        public  int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
            return RangeComparator(o1, o2);
            }



        public static void main(String[] args) {

            String url =null;
            String url2=null;
            String name = null;
            String password =null;
            Scanner ob=new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter the URL for  abc : ");
            url=ob.nextLine(); 
            System.out.println("Enter the URL for pqr : ");
            url2=ob.nextLine(); 
            System.out.println("Enter your Username :");
            name=ob.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter your Password :");
            password=ob.nextLine();


            setupLibrary();
            if (args != null) {
                url = (args.length >= 1) ? args[0] : url;
                url2 = (args.length >= 2) ? args[1] : url2;
                name = (args.length >= 3) ? args[2] : name;
                password = (args.length >= 4) ? args[3] : password;
            }
            SVNRepository repository = null;
            SVNRepository   repository2=null;
            try {

                repository2 = SVNRepositoryFactory.create(SVNURL.parseURIEncoded(url2));
                repository = SVNRepositoryFactory.create(SVNURL.parseURIEncoded(url));
            } catch (SVNException svne) {
                System.err
                .println("error while creating an SVNRepository for location '"
                        + url + "': " + svne.getMessage());
                System.exit(1);
            }

            ISVNAuthenticationManager authManager = SVNWCUtil.createDefaultAuthenticationManager(name, password);
            repository.setAuthenticationManager(authManager);

            try{
                SVNNodeKind nodeKind = repository.checkPath("", -1);
                if (nodeKind == SVNNodeKind.NONE) {
                    System.err.println("There is no entry at '" + url + "'.");
                    System.exit(1);
                } else if (nodeKind == SVNNodeKind.FILE) {
                    System.err.println("The entry at '" + url + "' is a file while a directory was expected.");
                    System.exit(1);
                }
                System.out.println("Repository Root  " + repository.getRepositoryRoot(true));
                System.out.println("Repository UUID  " + repository.getRepositoryUUID(true));
                System.out.println("");

                /*
                 * Displays the repository tree at the current path - "" (what means
                 * the path/to/repository directory)
                 */
                listEntries(repository, "");
            } catch (SVNException svne) {
                System.err.println("error while listing entries: "
                        + svne.getMessage());
                System.exit(1);
            }


            ISVNAuthenticationManager authManager2 = SVNWCUtil.createDefaultAuthenticationManager(name, password);
            repository2.setAuthenticationManager(authManager2);

            try{
                SVNNodeKind nodeKind2 = repository2.checkPath("", -1);
                if (nodeKind2 == SVNNodeKind.NONE) {
                    System.err.println("There is no entry at '" + url2 + "'.");
                    System.exit(1);
                } else if (nodeKind2 == SVNNodeKind.FILE) {
                    System.err.println("The entry at '" + url2 + "' is a file while a directory was expected.");
                    System.exit(1);
                }System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("======================================================");
                System.out.println("Repository Root " + repository2.getRepositoryRoot(true));
                System.out.println("Repository UUID  " + repository2.getRepositoryUUID(true));
                System.out.println("");

                listEntries2(repository2, "");
            } catch (SVNException svne) {
                System.err.println("error while listing entries: "
                        + svne.getMessage());
                System.exit(1);
            }
            //=======================================================================
            /*
             * Gets the latest revision number of the repository
             */





            long latestRevision = -1;

            try {
                latestRevision = repository.getLatestRevision();

            } catch (SVNException svne) {
                System.err
                .println("error while fetching the latest repository revision: "
                        + svne.getMessage());
                System.exit(1);
            }
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("Repository latest revision: " + latestRevision);

            long latestRevision2=-1;
        try{
            latestRevision2 = repository2.getLatestRevision();
            }catch(SVNException svne){
                System.err
                .println("error while fetching the latest repository revision: "
                        + svne.getMessage());
                System.exit(1);

            }
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("Repository2 latest revision: " + latestRevision2);
            System.exit(0);

        }

        /*
         * Initializes the library to work with a repository via 
         * different protocols.
         */
        private static void setupLibrary() {
            DAVRepositoryFactory.setup();
            SVNRepositoryFactoryImpl.setup();
            FSRepositoryFactory.setup();
        }




        static SVNDirEntry entry=null;  
        public static void listEntries(SVNRepository repository, String path)throws SVNException {
            Collection entries = repository.getDir(path, -1, null,
                    (Collection) null);
            Iterator iterator = entries.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                entry = (SVNDirEntry) iterator.next();

                System.out.println("/" + (path.equals("") ? "" : path + "/")
                        + entry.getName() + " (author: '" + entry.getAuthor()
                        + "'; revision: " + entry.getRevision() + "; date: " + entry.getDate() + ")");



                if (entry.getKind() == SVNNodeKind.DIR) {
                    listEntries(repository, (path.equals("")) ? entry.getName()
                            : path + "/" + entry.getName());
                    }
                  }
                 }

        static SVNDirEntry entry2=null; 
        public static void listEntries2(SVNRepository repository2, String path)throws SVNException {
            Collection entries2 = repository2.getDir(path, -1, null,
                    (Collection) null);
            Iterator iterator = entries2.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                entry2 = (SVNDirEntry) iterator.next();
                        System.out.println("/" + (path.equals("") ? "" : path + "/")
                        + entry2.getName() + " (author: '" + entry2.getAuthor()
                        + "'; revision: " + entry2.getRevision() + "; date: " + entry2.getDate() + ")");

                /*
                 * Checking up if the entry is a directory.
                 */
                if (entry2.getKind() == SVNNodeKind.DIR) {
                    listEntries2(repository2, (path.equals("")) ? entry2.getName()
                            : path + "/" + entry2.getName());

                    } 
                  }DisplayRep dp = new DisplayRep();
                  dp.compare(entry, entry2);
                 }


        private  int RangeComparator(Object o1, Object o2) {





            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("in comparator");
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            SVNDirEntry r1 = (SVNDirEntry) entry;
            SVNDirEntry r2 = (SVNDirEntry) entry2;
            //boolean r1revisiondate = r2.getRevision() > r1.getRevision(); 

            System.out.println("Node type : "+entry2.getKind());
            if(r2.getRevision()>r1.getRevision())
            {System.out.println(" ");
                System.out.println("abc :"+r2.getRevision()+"   date :"+r2.getDate());
                System.out.println("pqr :"+r1.getRevision()+"  date :"+r1.getDate());
            }
            else {
                System.out.println(" ");
            }
            return 1;

    }
    }
```